# Postgres connection actively refused

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I am having a problem connecting to postgres from my java app.I am able to login from pgAdminIII using postgres role and the right password

```
<db.host>127.0.0.1</db.host>
<db.port>5432</db.port>
<db.schema>test</db.schema>
<db.username>postgres</db.username>
<db.password>admin</db.password>
```

but when I try to connect from the app I am getting the following error:

> could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I haven't changed pg_hba.conf, by default it has the following parameters:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I also tried to disable Windows Firewall, nothing happened. It is really strange as I used to connect without a problem. If anyone can help it will be very much appreciated.

I am using postgres 9.4.

I have already checked the related question but none of them solves my problem.

Comment: Finally I run the goals clean and package from my IDE and worked!